# Design approach - using DI in a simple application

Tags: dependency-injection, inversion-of-control, constructor-injection

Hi I want to check to see if I am overthinking a design issue or not. I am quite new to DI/IoC/TDD so sorry if I am 
making an obvious mistake.

I have a simple application that will read from a Trade log, read some XML and then save to a database.

Ideally I want to create this application using a TDD approach with DI and possibly IoC.

So I have created some code (see below).

```
public interface IDataRepository
{
   void Save(object someObject);
}

public class DataRepository : IDataRepository
{
   public void Save(object someObject){}
}

Public interface ITradeXmlProcessor
{
    void ProcessXml;
}

public class TradeXmlProcessor : ITradeXmlProcessor
{
   IDataRepository iDataRepository;
   public void ProcessXml()
   {
      // Do work....
      SaveTradeData(someObject);
   }

   private void SaveTradeData(object someObject)
   {
       iDataRepository = new DataRepository();
       iDataRepository.Save(someObject));
   }
}

public class ProgramClass
{
   ITradeXmlProcessor iTradeXmlProcessor = new TradeXmlProcessor();
   iTradeXmlProcessor.ProcessXml(); 
}
```

Now to me the issue here is that when I go to test this code I am unable to mock the DataRepository object.

So I considered DI, which looks like :

```
public class TradeXmlProcessor : ITradeXmlProcessor
{
   private IDataRepository _iDataRepository;
   public TradeXmlProcessor(IDataRepository iDataRepository)
   {
    _iDataRepository = iDataRepository;
   }

   // Use _iDataRepository in process methods.

   // ...
}
```

In my program class I then can pass in a IDataRepository class but is this too much?
Is this the correct approach as well? I am a bit worried I might be missing something obvious?

Testability wise I am able to inject a mocked IDataRepository object into a ITradeXMLProcessor class, process it, but not save to the database which is good, but do I really need to mock such a simple operation? I cannot see the benefit I really gain from it?

```
public class ProgramClass
{
   IDataRepository iDataRepository = new DataRepository();
   ITradeXmlProcessor iTradeXmlProcessor = new TradeXmlProcessor(iDataRepository);
   iTradeXmlProcessor.ProcessXml(); 
}
```

Comment: "I want to create this application using a TDD approach with DI and possibly IoC" How do you distinguish beteween IoC and DI?

Comment: Since you want to use TDD, *start by writing a test* and see where that leads you. You're not using TDD if you write the SUT first.

Comment: Just in relation to this: " do I really need to mock such a simple operation" - if you want to be strictly isolated in your tests, then yes, you do - you will only mock the exact parts of the injected dependency interface that the particular test needs in order for the SUT to run. This ensures that any test failure is 100% attributable to the SUT and not for example, to a subtle bug in a concrete dependency which you don't even know about yet.

Answer (score 1):

Your approach to using DI to inject a service looks absolutely correct.

The question of whether you will get real benefit out of it is a matter of opinion, is not really a question for SO, and requires a lot more context.